# C++ - Expression must be modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++

I am new to C++.
I am trying to set up a very basic TCG game (with only minion with no text).

I think my issue might be linked with pointer.

Below are the functions and attributes:

```
Player *Game::Turn
Board Player::getBoard()
Card Card_collection::get(int i)
int Card::m_has_been_played_this_turn
```

Board inherits from Card_collection

I have:

```
(*Turn).getBoard().get(i).m_has_been_played_this_turn = 0;
```

And I have as a compiler error:

```
Expression must be modifiable lvalue '=' : left operand must be l-value
```

Please, where do you think is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this isn't the right place to ask this question, so for future reference ask these types of questions on Stack Overflow.

You don't really give enough code to be totally sure what's wrong, but one thing that comes to mind given the error is the following. First, note that your `get(int i)` method is returning a copy of a `Card`, not the actual ith `Card` from the Card Collection. This means when you do:

```
(*Turn).getBoard().get(i).m_has_been_played_this_turn = 0;
```

You are actually setting the `m_has_been_played_this_turn` variable for a temporary `Card` instance, which may be where the error is coming from since this temporary `Card` instance should be an `rvalue`, not a `lvalue`.

One way to change this might be to change your code to the following:

```
Card card_ = (*Turn).getBoard().get(i);
card_.m_has_been_played_this_turn = 0;
```

But this is still not going to accomplish what I believe you want, since `card_` is just a copy of the ith `Card` in your Card Collection. If you really want to modify the ith `Card` in your Card Collection, change the `get(int i)` definition to the following:

```
Card &  Card_collection::get(int i)
```

That `&` means you will pass a `Card` out of `get(int i)` by reference, allowing you to modify the `Card` within the Card Collection directly. Then the original code you wrote to set `m_has_been_played_this_turn` should be fine.